# Why is it not possible to perform isNotNull on a column that has DataType.SERIALIZABLE in ormlite?

Tags: java, android, ormlite

Using ORMLite 4.48 on Android, consider the following User table...

```java
@DatabaseTable(tableName = "users")
public class User {

    @DatabaseField(columnName = Column.UUID)
    protected String uuid;

    @DatabaseField(columnName = Column.FIRST_NAME)
    protected String firstName = null;

    @DatabaseField(columnName = Column.LAST_NAME)
    protected String lastName = null;

    @DatabaseField(columnName = Column.ADDRESS, dataType = DataType.SERIALIZABLE)
    protected Address address = null;

    // ...
}
```

(Address class represents a human readable address, translated from a lat/lon)

... with the following query...

```java
List<User> users = getDbHelper().getDao(User.class)
                .queryBuilder()
                .where()
                .isNotNull(User.Column.ADDRESS)
                .query();
```

... which throws this exception:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Field 'address' is of data type com.j256.ormlite.field.types.SerializableType@42ac7650 which can not be compared
        at com.j256.ormlite.stmt.query.BaseComparison.<init>(BaseComparison.java:27)
        at com.j256.ormlite.stmt.query.IsNotNull.<init>(IsNotNull.java:19)
        at com.j256.ormlite.stmt.Where.isNotNull(Where.java:315)
        ...
```

Apparently, an `IS NOT NULL` clause can not used on a field that is stored as DataType.SERIALIZABLE.

Digging through the ORMLite code, the BaseComparison constructor checks whether the fieldType is comparable:

https://github.com/j256/ormlite-core/blob/master/src/main/java/com/j256/ormlite/stmt/query/BaseComparison.java

```java
protected BaseComparison(String columnName, FieldType fieldType, Object value, boolean isComparison)
        throws SQLException {
    if (isComparison && fieldType != null && !fieldType.isComparable()) {
        throw new SQLException("Field '" + columnName + "' is of data type " + fieldType.getDataPersister()
                + " which can not be compared");
    }

    ...
}
```

Obviously, `SerializableType.isComparable()` returns `false`:

https://github.com/j256/ormlite-core/blob/master/src/main/java/com/j256/ormlite/field/types/SerializableType.java

```java
@Override
public boolean isComparable() {
    return false;
}
```

So, it is clear to me why the exception is thrown. But why is it not possible to do a `Where.isNull()` or `Where.isNotNull()`? Is it a SQLite restriction or did the author of ORMLite made this decision?

Answer (score 0):

Unsure about the "why", but I believe the "how" is to use a `ForeignCollectionField` instead of a `DatabaseField`